# plotting data in R from matlab

Tags: r, matlab, plot

I was wondering if it is possible to work between matlab and R to plot some data. I have a script in matlab which generates a text file. From this I was wondering if it was possible to open R from within matlab and plot the data from this text file and then return to matlab.

For example, if I save a text file called test.txt, in the path 'E:\', and then define the path of R which in my case will be:

```
pathR = 'C:\Program Files\R\R-2.14.1\bin\R';
```

Is it possible to run a script already written in R saved under test1.R (saved in the same directory as test.txt) in R from matlab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working with Windows (from the path it looks like you are), you can use the [MATLAB R-link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/5051) from the File Exchange to pass data from Matlab to R, execute commands there, and retrieve output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use R so this is not something I have done but I see no reason why you shouldn't be able to use the `system` function to call R from a Matlab session.  Look in the product documentation under the section [Run External Commands, Scripts, and Programs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-12994.html#f0-38522) for this and related approaches.

There are some platform-specific peculiarities to be aware of and you may have to wrestle a little with what is returned (though since you are planning to have R create a plot which is likely to be a side-effect rather than what is returned you may not).  As ever this is covered quite well in the product's documentation

Answer (score 0):

After using R(D)COM and Matlab R-link for a while, I do not recommend it. The COM interface has trouble parsing many commands and it is difficult to debug the code. I recommend using a system command from Matlab as described in the [R Wiki](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=tips:callingr:matlab). This also avoids having to install RAndFriends.